# Prove that $X$ is finite.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal T$ be the finite-closed topology on a set $X$. If $\mathcal T$ is also the discrete topology, prove that the set $X$ is finite.

My attempt:

We know that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal T$. But since $\mathcal T$ is the finite-closed topology, we know that $X\setminus \emptyset =X$ is closed, and consequently, finite.

This does not seem to make use of the fact that $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology on $X$. Can anyone please help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach does not work, because in the finite-closed topology (or co-finite topology) the closed sets are exactly all finite subsets of $X$ **and** $X$ itself, regardless of its size. That $X$ must be closed, follows because $\emptyset$ must always be open, according to the topology axioms.

So no info on $X$ is gained this way.

But take $\{x\}$ which should be open (in the discrete topology!) so its complement is closed **and** not equal to $X$. Now you do have a conclusion....